# Display div on hover on the div

Tags: html, css

I want to display `div` on hover. I have tried a lot but could not solve my issue. When I hover on `div` the `img_overlay` appears but it goes upside when hover.

```css
.main_image_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div {
  margin: auto;
}

.main_image_div .image_div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay {
  top: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p+p {
  top: 50px;
}

.main_image_div:hover .img_overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_image_div b">
  <div class="image_div">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg">
    <div class="img_overlay">
      <p>Change</p>
      <p>Delete</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean "goes upside" on hover?

Comment: when I hover it then the div goes upside.. it is moving upside. you can check my working code.

Comment: try putting class="img_overlay" in the img tag like this <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg"  class="img_overlay">

Comment: You want the div to stop moving when you hover?

Comment: @mlegg.. there are some text on img_overlay so I can't

Comment: @amflare.. yes exactly.. that is i want.. I simply want.. when I hove on image_div then img_overlay appears wihtout any movement of div

Comment: Not what's causing the problem, but one of your `divs` isn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:relative` on the parent element and `position:absolute` on the overlay

```css
.main_image_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.main_image_div .image_div {
  margin: auto;
}

.main_image_div .image_div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p+p {
  top: 50px;
}

.main_image_div:hover .img_overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_image_div b">
  <div class="image_div">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg">
    <div class="img_overlay">
      <p>Change</p>
      <p>Delete</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. I understand it needs some more styling. I use `position:absolute` and `position:relative`. The hover covers 100% of the div. Is this what you wanted?

```css
.main_image_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.main_image_div .image_div {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.main_image_div .image_div img {
  width: 100%;
}
.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay p + p {
  top: 50px;
}
.main_image_div:hover .img_overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_image_div b">
          <div class="image_div">
           <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" >
           <div class="img_overlay">
            <p>Change</p>
            <p>Delete</p>
           </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody is going overboard with their suggestions when the only change you need to make is `100px` to `100%` on the `height`...

```
.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay {
    height:100%;
}
```

And by doing this, you won't have any gray box popping out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way to do that, but if you need a quick fix change the following

```
.main_image_div .image_div {
    position: relative;
}

.main_image_div .image_div .img_overlay {
    top: -16px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.main_image_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.main_image_div .image_div {
  margin: auto;
}

.main_image_div .image_div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image_div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}

.main_image_div:hover .img_overlay {
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_image_div b">
  
  <div class="image_div">
    <img src="http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg" >
    
    <div class="img_overlay">
    <p>Change</p>
      <p>Delete</p>
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```